# list index out of range in python..?

Tags: python, math, keyerror

here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\Downloads\#swig.py", line 45, in <module>
    print("Mode =", numdict2[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

here is my code:

```
lennumlist = int(1)
x = 1
y = 0
newlist = []
added = 0
numlist = []
while x < 6:
    print("This is number",x)
    num1 = int(input("Number?"))
    x = x + 1
    numlist.append(num1)
print("Your numbers =", numlist)
print("Calculating mean...")
while y < 5:
    num = numlist[y]
    added = added + num
    y = y + 1
divide = added / len(numlist)
print("Your mean is", divide)
print("Calculating mode...")
numlist.sort
numdict = {}
numlist1 = []
listlength = len(numlist)
x = 1
for x in range (0,listlength):
    if not numlist[x] in numdict:
        numdict[numlist[x]]=1
    else:
        numdict[numlist[x]] = numdict[numlist[x]] + 1
numdict1 = []
numdict1 = sorted(numdict.values())
numdict2 = []
nummy = int(len(numdict1))
print(numdict1)
print(numdict)
for x in range (1, nummy):
    print(x)
    if numdict[x] == numdict1[x]:
        numdict2.append(numdict[x])
if len(numdict2) > 1:
    print("Modes =", numdict2)
else:
    print("Mode =", numdict2[1])
```

I've been getting this error for a while.
my program is designed to calculate the mean and the mode of numbers inputted by the user.
My teacher tells me that this is normally caused by trying to add a string and an integer. any help? :(

Comment: Start by removing a lot of code. As a beginner, you are not going to find a bug in 60 lines of code. Remove every line that actually works, and keep only the lines that don't work. When you have done this, the bug will be staring you in the face. If you can write 7 lines of code that have the same bug, then I can help you, if you haven't found it yourself by then.

Comment: You're getting a KeyError because your dict doesn't have the key `0`.

Comment: @limelights: `numdict2` is actually a list (confusing, I know), which is also indicated by the error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: BTW: Tel your teacher they are wrong, this error could never be caused by adding a `str` and an `int`...

Comment: @cdarke there has been a few edits since my comment, at first it was a KeyError.

Comment: @limelights: OK, sorry about that.  This is trying to hit a moving target.

Answer (score 0):

List-indexes in Python start from *zero*, so in the case you have when there's only one entry in the `numdict2` *list* then you can't use anything but zero as index.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying - I changed my code to for x in range (0, nummy - 1):
    if numdict[x] == numdict1[x]:

Comment: @JoeWilliams Read the error message again, and what line of code it points out. It's *that* line that I'm talking about.

Comment: I stopped getting the error (no idea how) but now when it's meant to tell me the mode it just says Mode: []

Comment: what I want to do is on this line: `if numdict[x] == numdict1[x]:`, instead of having numdict[x], I want to find the value that accompanies key number x.

Comment: @JoeWilliams It seems you have (or had) two different problems, if so then you should ask two different questions!

Answer (score 0):

You have the code:

```
if len(numdict2) > 1:
    print("Modes =", numdict2)
else:
    print("Mode =", numdict2[1])
```

If the length of the list is not greater than 1, then it is (at best) one element.  Python (like most languages) lists start their element indexes from zero, not one.  So the line should be:

```
print("Mode =", numdict2[0])
```

However, you should also code for the possibility that the list could be empty.

By the way, it is very confusing using a name like `numdict2` for a **list**, maybe `numlist2` might be better?

EDIT:
So now you have a different error to the one you posted:

```
if numdict[x] == numdict1[x]:
```

When a list (or dictionary) is initialised with `[]` (or `{}`) it is empty, so it doesn't even have index zero in it.  You can test for something in the list with:

```
if numdict1:
```

This gives True if there is something there, False if it is empty.

Comment: ok, but I still don't understand why I'm getting the keyerror on if numdict[x] == numdict1[x]:

Comment: I knew this already but 
 
 
what I want to do is on this line: if numdict[x] == numdict1[x]:, instead of having numdict[x], I want to find the value that accompanies key number x.

Comment: @JoeWilliams: but what do you do if the list is empty?